# Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "html: function(){return getInstructions() }" ( Magento 2 )

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, knockoutjs

I'm using a third party one page checkout module on this system. And added an observer "payment_method_is_active" event for the cash on delivery and bank transfer methods to enable them only for local orders.

This is how payment method hiding works at the observer.

```
if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"){
        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);
        if($getCountry == 'LK'){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            return $checkResult->setData('is_available', true); //this is enabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
        else {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            return $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
```

**When the cart page loads:** If the country is selected to a foreign country, cart page loads hiding both payment methods without any errors, then if I change it to the default country, it loads the two methods with this error.

[image]

The same error appears for the bank transfer method also.

**When the cart page loads:** But, If the country is selected to the default at page reload, both payment methods shows on the page without any errors. And the hiding / showing methods working nicely according to the country selection without any error.

Please help to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to have any luck with solving this. I'm facing this exact problem right now and have no idea where to begin...

Comment: Can you share js code for cashondelivery-method.js?

Comment: can you put full code of observer file ???

Answer (score 0):

Replace This code with this :-

> From :-

```
if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"){
        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);
        if($getCountry == 'LK'){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            return $checkResult->setData('is_available', true); //this is enabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
        else {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            return $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
```

> To :-

```
if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"){
        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);
        if($getCountry == 'LK'){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', true); //this is enabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
        else {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a plugin/module.

It can be easily managed to form the Admin configuration:

go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods

in most of the payment method you will see the option for:

```
Payment from Applicable Countries: Change it to Specific Countries

Payment from Specific Countries: Exclude the country you don't wish to enable payment method.
```